# Dynamic size of subviews of UITableViewCell with storyboard prototypes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, storyboard

I am using storyboard to define one of the prototype cells as "Custom" and adding a `UITextField`. There is a label (with static text) to the left of it. It sort of looks like the "Right Detail" cell type, only that the right part is editable.

Is there a way to economically resize the text field so it reaches from the end of the text label to the right edge? The text label on the left should be just big enough to show it's text.

I know about `sizeToFit` and `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:`, but the resizing of the subviews seems rather cumbersome and will have to be repeated with each recycling of a cell.

Is there a way to work with `autoresizingMask` of `UIView`, perhaps by specifying this in IB /storyboard?

Comment: I changed the editable side, think that's what you meant? How much text are you expecting to put in the editable text field? 20 characters, 20 lines?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Field contents is max one line. The view controller is for editing, the data does not even have to be displayed completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel I let you down on the previous question, so here goes something with a bit more effort.

You can try something like the following. This is only a sample project to give you a rough idea, but it works pretty well.

I created an empty project with a single table view controller. This had a hardcoded number of sections (1) and rows (10). I had a single prototype cell, of the `Basic` type. You can set any view you like as the accessory view, so I have used a text field. All the magic therefore happens in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (!cell.accessoryView)
    {
        UITextField *accessory = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 30.0)];
        accessory.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine; // Just so you can see the effect
        cell.accessoryView = accessory;
    }

    NSMutableString *text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"A"];

    for (int i = 0; i < indexPath.row; i++) {
        [text appendFormat:@"A"]; // Just to illustrate different sizes
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = text;

    CGSize labelSize = [cell.textLabel.text sizeWithFont:cell.textLabel.font];
    CGRect accessoryFrame = cell.accessoryView.frame;

    accessoryFrame.size.width = cell.bounds.size.width - labelSize.width - 40; 
    // 40 is a magic number to prevent overlaps, you could be cleverer here
    // You'd also want to restrict to some minimum width.
    cell.accessoryView.frame = accessoryFrame;

    return cell;
}
```

Key points:

- You only need to resize the accessory view.
- The text field is pretty basic - typically you'd want a little factory method that returns one for you, setting the delegate, and probably a toolbar as an accessory view with previous, next and done buttons
- Assigning the value entered in the text field back to the data model is an exercise left for the reader.

This produces the following output:

[image]

Comment: Very neat solution. Perfectly clear and economical. I had thought of the `accessoryView` but we have to abandon designing everything in IB. Well, this is a good compromise. Thank you!